# How to play youtube video using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, youtube-iframe-api

All the following code is work successfully to get youtube playlist and display it with no problem. But I can't play any video from this list using angular js.

**Angular JS**

```
   var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
   app.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
       //contentDetails - snippet

       $http.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=50&playlistId=PLlMsyZB0poTDYImmOliKyiC-jpAFUsr6X&key=AIzaSyDGm1uzuqPPUGzG-qN7u6gTaS8ApXBJYvw')
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.records = response.data.items;
            });

       $scope.PlayFun = function (Val) {
           var Vid_ID = Val;
           var New_Vid = "<iframe width='450' height='283' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + Vid_ID + "?autoplay=1&loop=1&rel=0&wmode=transparent' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen wmode='Opaque'></iframe>";
           var Vid_Elm = document.getElementById("video");

           Vid_Elm.setAttribute("crs", New_Vid);

       };

   });
```

**HTML**

```
    <iframe id="video" style="position:fixed;top:150px;right:50px;" width="420" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/9B7te184ZpQ?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

    <br />

    <ul data-ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <li data-ng-repeat="x in records">
                    <img class="img-thumbnail" style="width:100px; height:80px;" 
                    src="{{x.snippet.thumbnails.default.url}}" />
            <br />

            <input data-ng-click="PlayFun(x.snippet.resourceId.videoId)" type="button" value="{{x.snippet.title}}" />
        </li>
    </ul>
```

My problem specifically is in "$scope.PlayFun" where I can't run a video from the list by video id using angular js. 
My approach is to change iframe html on ng-click to pass new selected Vid_ID and to make it "autoplay=1" put it doesn't work.

Comment: I think the mistake is in this line :`Vid_Elm.setAttribute("crs", New_Vid);`. It's src not crs.

Comment: yes @ Alexandru-Ionut Mihai that's right :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the src of the iframe to ng-src like so:

```
<iframe id="video" style="position:fixed;top:150px;right:50px;" width="420" height="315" ng-src="{{videoSource}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

And in your controller you simply change the url of video source and it will automatically change the video source. You do need to trust as resource url though for security (which means injected $sce as well)

```
$scope.videoSource = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("//www.youtube.com/embed/9B7te184ZpQ?rel=0");
```

[Working PLunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/t5v29szIGSPA3LoFXyJL)

Comment: That's very useful for me. But you forgot to mention to add $sce as an angular js function parameter like this "function ($scope, $http, $sce)".  thank you anyway @Tim Andrews.

Comment: I said you need to inject $sce above, and I also include it in the plunker i linked.